# Setters/Getters Removed During Kotlin Conversion

Tags: java, android, kotlin

After converting a Java based model class to Kotlin, I noticed that my setter and getter methods were removed. What was once,

```
private String apiKey;

public void setApiKey(String key) {
   this.key = key;
}

public String getApiKey() {
   return key;
}
```

Became

```
lateinit var apiKey: String
```

What happened, exactly? Did it remove my setters and getters and then change the access modifier of my variable from private to public? If so, why and how is this good? Setters and getters are meant to be part of abstraction in Java. Kotlin does not care about this?

I am still learning Kotlin, and I am relying on the built in conversions as a beginner's guide to best practices. Is it just a situation where you do not do setters/getters in Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin has implied getters and setters https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did it remove my setters and getters and then change the access modifier of my variable from private to public?

Yes.

> If so, why

It generated idiomatic Kotlin for the code that you had.

> how is this good?

Idiomatic Kotlin is a reasonable default choice for a code translator to Kotlin.

> Setters and getters are meant to be part of abstraction in Java. Kotlin does not care about this?

Sure it does. However, your existing setter and getter weren't doing anything, so the Kotlin conversion removed them, electing to use the default setter and getter that already exist.

Let's suppose instead that your code looked like this:

```
private String apiKey;

public void setApiKey(String key) {
   this.key = key.toUpperCase();
}

public String getApiKey() {
   return key;
}
```

Here, the setter is enforcing that an API key is always in uppercase.

The equivalent Kotlin would be:

```
var apiKey: String = "THE-DUDE-ABIDES"
  set(value) { field = value.toUpperCase() }
```

Consumers of your `apiKey` property are always using getters and setters. It's just that, syntactically, Kotlin makes calling getters and setters look like accessing a simple field. So, consumers of `apiKey` do not need to do anything different to use your overridden setter (with the `toUpperCase()` call) from the default setter.

Comment: Wow, very good response. This is crystal clear now. I see. I guess my IDE knew what it was doing all along :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your field + getter/setter have been converted to [Kotlin Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html). Because a field + getter/setter is super common, Kotlin has top level support for it. It might look like you are accessing the bare field directly, but that's not the case. Kotlin is hiding the default implementation of the getter and the setter from you. In most cases, we just want to a get or set without any other logic, so we don't need to see it. Any time you access `apiKey` in Kotlin, you are going through the getter or the setter.

As for why it is public, properties are public in Kotlin by default. How to provide your own implementations of get/set, as well as how to change their access levels can be found on the page I've linked to above.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to read a good documentation about `Kotlin` like for example [property-getter-and-setter-kotlin](https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/property-getter-and-setter-kotlin-d89a3e70e62) but I'll give to you a little example...

It's normal that they removed `setter` and `getter`, they still there... The thing is that if you want to `override` these `set` and `get` you should do something like :

```
private var apiKey: String
get() = "My apiKey is $apiKey"
set(value) {
    //Do whatever you want with apiKey
}
```

So, if you don't want to `override` these methods, you can simply access to it using:

if you do `apiKey = ...` you are using a **set**

if you use `var newVar = apiKey` you are using the **get** method